# What does this mean List < Class <? extends DataType>>?

Tags: java

I ran into a below statement which expects aforementioned parameter type while reviewing oracle entitlement server API.

```
FunctionEntry functionEntry = ...;
functionEntry.setParameterTypes(List<Class<? extends DataType>>);
```

I am having a hard time to understand what it is asking for. I only understand "? extends DataType". What type of parameter I need to pass into setParameterTypes method?

Comment: [java.lang.Class<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List<Class<?>>` is a list of `Class` objects e.g.

```
Arrays.asList(String.class, Boolean.class, Pattern.class)`
```

A `List<Class<? extends T>>` is a list that can only contain the `Class` objects of T and its subclasses e.g. `List<Class<? extends CharSequence>>` could be

```
Arrays.asList(String.class, StringBuffer.class, StringBuilder.class, CharSequence.class)`
```

The statement defines *the* type of each parameter that the `FunctionEntry` takes. Although, the way you typed it is not syntactically correct. The definition of `setParameterTypes` is

```
setParameterTypes(java.util.List<java.lang.Class<? extends DataType>> parameters)
```

So it is expecting a list of classes corresponding to the parameter types of the function you are defining, with the added requirement that the types must be subclasses of `DataType`. For example, the classes `OpssBoolean`, `OpssInteger` and `OpssDouble` are subclasses of DataType in the Oracle API. So if you wanted to define a function in this API that takes an `OpssBoolean` as 1st parameter, an `OpssInteger` as 2nd parameter, and an `OpssDouble` as 3rd parameter, you define it this way:

```
List<java.lang.Class<? extends DataType>> parameterTypes = Arrays.asList(
    OpssBoolean.class, OpssInteger.class, OpssDouble.class
);
functionEntry.setParameterTypes(parameterTypes);
```

Answer (score 2):

It asks for a list of specific `Class` objects. In this case a list of `Class` objects which represent classes which extends from the `DataType` class. When you extends from this class like:

```
public class MySpecialDataType extends DataType
{
}

public class AnotherDataTypeToUse extends DataType
{
}
```

you can use the expressions `MySpecialDataType.class` and `AnotherDataTypeToUse.class` (something called "class literal") to get objects which can be assigned to `Class<? extends DataType>` variables.

```
Class<MySpecialDataType> clazzOne = MySpecialDataType.class;
Class<AnotherDataTypeToUse> clazzTwo = AnotherDataTypeToUse.class;
Class<? extends DataType> baseClazz = clazzOne; // works
baseClazz = clazzTwo; // also works
List<Class<? extends DataType>> clazzes = new ArrayList<Class<? extends DataType>>();
clazzes.add(clazzOne);
clazzes.add(clazzTwo);

functionEntry.setParameterTypes(clazzes);
```

You might want to look at [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) for the argument of `setParameterTypes()`.

Answer (score -1):

It returns a list of input parameters.

Lets say, this function takes a variable number of input parameters, it will return the TYPES of minimum required inputs.
For example, logical functions AND and OR can take an unbound number of input parameters but require minimum 2 OpssBoolean type parameters. So this method will return {OpssBoolean.class,OpssBoolean.class} for AND or OR functions.

Comment: What question did you try to answer?

Comment: "I am having a hard time to understand what it is asking for."
I was trying to explain that this functionEntry.setParameterTypes(List<Class<? extends DataType>>);
returns a list of input parameters.

Unfortunately, i dint see that the ques was asked for what parameters. But my example included the class parameters, which is kind of what he asked for (although not exact)

Comment: Really: You are trying to explain that a _setter_ (a method whose name starts with "set") returns a list of input parameters? This is simply wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Its asking that objects within `List` should extend `DataType` class

Answer (score -1):

It is asking you to pass a `List<MyDataType>` where

```
public class MyDataType extends DataType
{
    /* your data type stuff */
}
```

See here for details on DataType: **https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html**